# spying dynamic property in jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ionic4

I went through couple of examples but could not correlate my case on how to spy on dynamic properties.

A simple Orders and Order-details in ionic 4 application. A list of orders in Orders page and upon click on one of the order it passes whole order object to order details page.

Below is the order details page.

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-order-details',
  templateUrl: './order-details.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-details.page.scss'],
})
export class OrderDetailsPage implements OnInit {

  orderData: Order;
  users: Map<any, any>;
  location$: Subscription;
  data = {order : null};

  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,

  ) {
    //const data = this.dataService.getData();
    this.data = this.dataService.getData();
    this.orderData = this.data.order;

  }
```

In short, fetching **order** data from dataService.getData() and using in order-details page.

Below is the order-details-spec.ts

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { OrderDetailsPage } from './order-details.page';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from "@angular/common/http/testing";
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';



describe('OrderDetailsPage', () => {
  let component: OrderDetailsPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OrderDetailsPage>;
  let datasvcSpy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {

     var datasvc = new DataService();
    spyOn(datasvc,"getData").and.returnValue({order : {id : "12",description:"desc"}});

    //spyOn(component.data,'order'). and.returnValue({id : "12",description:"desc"});

    //datasvcSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('DataService',["getData"]);


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [OrderDetailsPage],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot([]),
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrderDetailsPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    //component.data = { order: { id: "123", description: "desc" } };
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

All the comments in the above file are various trails but did not work.

Below is the npm run test report:

```
Chrome 80.0.3987 (Mac OS X 10.14.6): Executed 2 of 10 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.542 secs)
Chrome 80.0.3987 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) OrderDetailsPage should create FAILED
        Failed: Cannot read property 'order' of undefined
        error properties: Object({ ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 33669121, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 114688, directChildFlags: 114688, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 1, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'app-order-details', attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: Object({ nodeIndex: 1, parent: <circular reference: Object>, renderParent: <circular reference: Object>, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 1, flags: 114688, childFlags: 0, directChildFlags: 0, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object, matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object, ngContentIndex: -1, childCount: 0, bindings: Array, bindingFlags: 0, outputs ...
            at <Jasmine>
            at new OrderDetailsPage (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/orderDetails/components/order-details/order-details.page.ts:28:32)
            at createClass (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31991:1)
            at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31807:1)
            at createViewNodes (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:44210:1)
            at createRootView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:44082:1)
            at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:45632:1)
            at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:44848:1)
            at ComponentFactory_.create (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:30788:1)
            at initComponent (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.js:3946:1)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
        Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/orderDetails/components/order-details/order-details.page.spec.ts:41:23)
            at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/z
```

**edit #2**

Modified spec file after the advice:

```
describe('OrderDetailsPage', () => {
  let component: OrderDetailsPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OrderDetailsPage>;
  let datasvcSpy;
  let mockDataService = { getData: () => { } };


  beforeEach(async(() => {

    var datasvc = new DataService();


    mockDataService = spyOn(datasvc, "getData").and.returnValue({ order: { id: "12", description: "desc" } });




    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [OrderDetailsPage],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot([]),

      ],
      providers: [{ provide: DataService, useValue: mockDataService }]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrderDetailsPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

but it is leading to compilation error:

```
ERROR in src/app/orderDetails/components/order-details/order-details.page.spec.ts:23:5 - error TS2741: Property 'getData' is missing in type 'Spy<() => any>' but required in type '{ getData: () => void; }'.

23     mockDataService = spyOn(datasvc, "getData").and.returnValue({ order: { id: "12", description: "desc" } });
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/orderDetails/components/order-details/order-details.page.spec.ts:15:27
    15   let mockDataService  = {getData: () => {} };
                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue of Dependency injection of service. Can you please using mocked dependency injection of service. I have created a service for you below:

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { OrderDetailsPage } from './order-details.page';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from "@angular/common/http/testing";
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';



describe('OrderDetailsPage', () => {
  let component: OrderDetailsPage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OrderDetailsPage>;
  let datasvcSpy;
  let mockDataService = {getData: () => {} };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    mockDataService = spyOn(datasvc,"getData").and.returnValue({order : {id : "12",description:"desc"}});


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [OrderDetailsPage],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot([]),
      ],
      providers: [provide: DataService, useValue: mockDataService]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OrderDetailsPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: I think it progressed but got new error.. 
Chrome 80.0.3987 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) OrderDetailsPage should create FAILED
        Failed: this.dataService.getData is not a function

Comment: My mistake, updated the answer again. See this line ->   let mockDataService = {getData: () => {} };

Comment: seems some compilation error after adding it. added the modified spec file and compilation error message.

Comment: i have started a chat, can you please discuss there?